# UITextView not becoming first responder

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I have a `UIView` that contains a `UITextView`. The `UIView` is initiated inside a `UIViewController`.

But when I touch the `UITextView` box, nothing happens. Neither the keyboard appears nor delegate methods respond to interaction.

Code:

```
    noteText = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 700, 240)];
    noteText.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.2].CGColor;
    noteText.layer.borderWidth = 2;
    [noteText setEditable:YES];
    noteText.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    noteText.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    noteText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Calibri" size:16];
    noteText.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self addSubview:noteText];
```

**Update 1**

I removed all other views from the UIViewController, and only put a UITextView in the UIViewController and still not reacting. Neither cursor or keyboard appear.

Comment: Make sure "user interaction enabled" is checked on view attributes at interface builder.

Comment: I don't use IB, but I have setted [textview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES] and [textview setEnabled]

Comment: did you tried [textview setDelegate:self]; ?

Comment: What are the dimensions of its superview?

Comment: The textview will open the keyboard automatically when you touch it, that should react even that I don't have set the delegate.
But I have set the delegate from the UIViewController. Since the must part of the logical of the app happen in the uiviewcontroller.

Comment: @CarlVeazey the dimension of the UIView is 40, 80, 750, 250. So is sligthly bigger. The border of the textview is shown inside the size of the UIView.

Comment: Did you add another subview to the UITextView's superview after the text view is added?

Comment: Not in the UIView. The UIView contains only this UITextView. But the UIViewController has anothers subviews, but not in that frame.
And the switching between subviews is controlled by a custom segmentedcontroller and all the other views is hidden when is not selected.

Comment: Seems like there could be another view's frame on top of the textView that's intercepting touch events.

Comment: Try subclassing the text view and overriding touchesBegan:
Then try subclassic the superview and in its touchesBegan: try to find which view is getting the touches using hitTest: ?

Comment: Now I have had remove all the others subview from superview, I'd subclassed the textview and overwritten touchesBegan:withEvent: class, and overwritten the same method in the UIView. Nothing works. I even bring it to the front. If I put some text string in the text appears, but I cant write.

Comment: what size of UIView that contains a UITextfield?

Comment: The UIView have the frame coordinates: `40, 80, 750, 250` and the frame of the UITextview is `0,0,700,240`

Comment: Are you releasing the UITextView after adding as subview of UIView? Try commenting out that portion and check it. Could be a release issue also.

Comment: I use ARC. So I don't need to release.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the error.

In one class I categorize the UITextView instead of subclass and set canBecomeFirstResponder to NO.

Answer (score 7):

```
noteText = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 700, 240)];
noteText.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.2].CGColor;
noteText.layer.borderWidth = 2;
[noteText setEditable:YES];
noteText.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
noteText.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
noteText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Calibri" size:16];
noteText.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self addSubview:noteText];
```

// Two suggestions

```
self.userInteractionEnabled = YES; // superview may blocks touches
self.clipsToBounds = YES; // superview may clips your textfield, you will see it
```

Comment: In my case it was exactly that, the UITextField superview was being resized by autolayout but I couldn't notice it because it wasn't clipping to bounds.

Comment: In my case it was also that AutoLayout compressed the view, but because clipsToBounds was No, it showed anyway.  Thanks.

Comment: for me adding `textView.userInteractionEnabled = true
            textView.editable = true` worked, I thought this was default behavior, guess it's possible it was getting set somewhere I'm unaware of

Answer (score 3):

try this:
in your .h file conform the delegate UITextViewDelegate

```
:<UITextViewDelegate>
```

in your .m file:

```
noteText.delegate = self;
```

And delegate methods:

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
    [textView becomeFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
    //resign for exapmple
    return YES;
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: the builtin `becomeFirstResponder` calls `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` so this will cause an infinite loop

Answer (score 3):

I know it's late, but maybe for someone it'll be helpful. I had the same problem, and it disappeared after I used

```
[self setSelectable:true];
```

in  my UITextView subclass.

Answer (score 2):

Check this things:

1. add your viewcontroller on the right `UIWindow`.
2. set window    `makeKeyAndVisible` and add `rootViewController` to window at this    method:

   -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

   I think here is something wrong in xib file or at `appdelegate`.

Comment: I don't know what you means here. Is not a problem to load the rootviewcontroller in UIWindow. Neither do I use xib-files.

Answer (score 1):

Try overriding `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {` inside the UIView to see if it's receiving touches

Just in case, try setting `userInteractionEnabled = YES;` for your UIView object. If it's somehow set as NO it will trickle down to all of its subviews

Comment: I have overwritten the method, but is not responding.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have some mistake in your overriden `-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` method? Maybe you do `resignFirstResponder` there or put some view above all?

Comment: For the moment the method only looks like this for see if the view react: `-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    NSLog(@"Received Touch!");
}
 `

Comment: Do you use `[self addSubview:noteText];` or `[self.view addSubview:noteText];`?

Comment: Since noteText that is a UITextView is subview of the UIView class named NoteView. There I use `[self addSubview:noteText]`, NoteView is subviewed in the UIViewController and there I use `[selv.view addSubview:noteView]`

Comment: Does cursor appear when you tap on you textView?

Comment: Nope. Even the keyboard won't appear. But if I hard code text, the string appear in the textview.

Comment: I think that some view lay above your textView. try to use `[self bringSubviewToFront:yourTextView]` and also bring all views which content yourTextView to front.

Comment: Look at my last update. Removed all other views and still not working. Have already tried bringSubviewToFront:

Comment: how you initialize your ViewController?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever something like this happens check the following items,

1. Make sure that the Text view is properly retained and released only in `dealloc`.(If you are not using `ARC`)
2. Check the frame of both Text view and it's parent views. Make sure that the `subview` is fitting exactly inside the parent view. Also make sure that this is the case with all the `superviews` of text view.
3. Check whether the `delegate` is set properly.

If all these are done, try adding a button on top of text view and check if it's `target selector` is getting called. If yes, the issue is with text view delegate or release statement. Otherwise the issue is with frame setting of Text view or it's superviews.